# Pop-up opens automatically

Tags: android, popup

I have a little issue with my app. When I click on my Activity the pop-up open when I simply want it to open after we select one of the language.
Can someone help me with it and explain why it does thata and how to improve it?

Thanks a lot!

```
public class LocalizationUpdaterActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] languages = { "English", "Francais", "Espanol", "Ivrit" };
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_langues);

        SharedPreferences sp = this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("loginSaved", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();


        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setPrompt("select language");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView arg0, View arg1,
                                       int arg2, long arg3) {
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                switch (arg2) {
                    case 0:
                        config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
                        editor.putString("Langues", "en_US");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        config.locale = Locale.FRENCH;
                        editor.putString("Langues", "fr_FR");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        config.locale = new Locale("es_ES");
                        editor.putString("Langues", "es_ES");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        config.locale = new Locale("he", "IL");
                        editor.putString("Langues", "he_IL");
                        break;
                    default:
                        config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
                        editor.putString("Langues", "en_US");
                        break;
                }
                popup("Warning !","The App will retart to apply the changes");
                getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }

    public void killApplication(Activity activity) {
        //Broadcast the command to kill all activities
        Intent intent = new Intent("kill");
        intent.setType("content://all");
        activity.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public void restartApplication() {
        killApplication(this);

        //Start the launch activity
        Intent i = this.getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(this.getBaseContext().getPackageName());
        this.startActivity(i);
    }
    public void popup(String titre, String texte) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,
                AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(titre).setMessage(texte)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        LocalizationUpdaterActivity.this.restartApplication();
                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialogBuilder.show();
    }

    public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
        final int buffer_size = 1024;
        try {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer_size];
            for (;;) {
                int count = is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
                if (count == -1)
                    break;
                os.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write setOnItemSelectedListener separately and set it in Post for spinner

```
spinner.post(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
   }  
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! It works the only probleme is that when i select the first language on the spinner it doesn't trigger the pop-up do you maybe know why ?